# 1995 Ford Aerostar van, AW hi, 4.0, 140,000 miles, white smoke with no smell under hard acceleration

Tags: ford, smoke

1995 Ford Aerostar van, AWD, 4.0, 140,000 miles.
On a recent trip leaving Vegas pulling a pretty good load with the outside temperature 110 and  with the AC and cruise on while pulling a pretty good grade, the van started dropping speed after the downshift and emitting a lot of white smoke with no smell. No missing or stumbling or cutting out and the engine temperature was normal. After topping the grade the smoking stopped and the van ran normally. Did it again 600 miles later under the same conditions and then back to normal. No starting problems, no shifting issues and coolant, oil and tranny fluid OK.
I had just refueled for the first time on the trip prior to the first time this occurred and to my surprise on my next refueling the mileage had jumped from 14 to 19 and subsequent refuels were 18 and 19. This van had always been right around 15 since I've owned it.
I'm obviously all in on the mileage jump but concerned about the smoke issue.
The van has vapor locked on me on a few times when the outside temperature is over 100 as the engine compartment is so crowded and gets very hot.
Other than that no issues, just curious about the smoke issue. Where there's smoke there's fire they say and it's gotta be coming from somewhere.

Comment: Mileage improvement due to a long constant speed trip.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! White smoke to me could either be coolant in the combustion chamber or tranny fluid burning against part of the exhaust system. In this case, I'd be looking at the transmission losing tranny fluid. It doesn't take much to make white smoke with it. When under a lot of pressure, transmission fluid can find ways of pushing out of seals which you wouldn't see when there isn't as much pressure. I'd look under the vehicle to see if there is any "wet" areas. Until you do a true inspection (other than checking fluids) you won't really know.

Comment: I also think the tranny fluid is likely the culprit. Shortly after I bought this van two years ago I made a trip in 106 degree temps and when I parked it I noticed that it had puked out a big spot of fluid that I figured came from the rear seal. I hadn't noticed any smoke and it never did it again. I live in southern Arizona where summer temps are way over 100 for two or three months but my driving is easy and mostly on the level so probably not building up the pressure like on this last trip. I stopped at a rest area after the last smoke and it dripped some tranny fluid, so that is telling.

Comment: Solar Mike...agree with you on the trip making a difference in mileage but it never made a difference before, still made 15 to 16 . The two fillups when I made 18+ and almost 20 I had fueled at Love's. I don't usually fill at Love's so who knows?       The best mileage was made after the big grade in the high temperatures with the smoke issue. Don't know, I always squeeze in as much as possible when fueling....anyway it was a pleasant surprise. When I refueled at my destination it was down to 17... Probably just a fluke but maybe I'll try Love's again.....

Comment: Is it dragging in brake fluid into the engine? A tiny amount can make a lot of white dense smoke.

Comment: @Desertdon - Yes, different fuel can make a difference. I have noticed with Shell fuel, while the engine runs just fine, my vehicles get a 3-4 mpg hit. This isn't just once or twice, it is something I've recognized over the years (more than 20) when I've had to use Shell gas because nothing else is available. This is also with different vehicles. I don't know why, but it's happened every time. IOW: the gas itself can make a difference.

Comment: Also High load uphill drives demand turning  off overdrive or downing shifting as the torque damages the transmission from slipping. Adding an extra tranny fluid cooler may have helped but now?

Comment: Paulster2, I agree about the fuel. I'm going to go with Love's when I can get it. Arizona has a lot of them but where I'm at in central Washington for a few weeks they don't have any stations so I'll have to wait till I get home.

Comment: SunnyskyguyEE75......I had the cruise on and it downshifted out of overdrive right away so I don't think it did any damage to the tranny. The engine wasn't even close to overheating either and it was a pretty good grade, It was another thousand miles to my destination and it shifted perfectly and I'm keeping an eye on the fluid level